# How can i solve my error during importing pygame

Tags: python, module, pygame, pycharm

*I try to install pygame in my pycharm Terminal using pip install pygame, but i got this error you can see beneath*

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\lvdbruinhorst\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja0kww2k\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\lvdbruinhorst\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja0kww2k\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\lvdbruinhorst\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja0kww2k\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\lvdbruinhorst\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja0kww2k\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\lvdbruinhorst\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja0kww2k\pygame\
```

*i also make a path in my systemvariables*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to install pygame from the PyCharm Terminal and it worked for me so there must be a different problem. Try to install this wheel file
[pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/e6/a0e790157db7dc6b62192d09a93085bcb2a5261ee45ddc4d6d225ecc4a4d/pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl), and then go to the directory it is installed and run `python -m pip install pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl` in the command prompt or pycharm's terminal

If you have multiple python versions you should use `py -3.X -m pip install pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl`.

If that doesn't work try updating pip wheel and setuptools.

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools`

If anyone has a better answer or knows what the problem is exactly please post it (I'm just guessing what could have gone wrong).

Comment: Yes this is for a windows os, I am using windows 10. I don't know if it would work on linux but I believe it would be easier to install the wheel.

Comment: This is what i got in the cmd: 'install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: i think i got it i run this command *pip install pygame* and i got this back: Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.9.6)